# In Java 8, how to get Stream<T> from Stream<? extends Collection<T>>?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8, using the packages `java.util.function` and `java.util.stream` as well as the new language features *lambda* and *method references*, what is the best way to turn a `Stream<Collection<T>>` into a `Stream<T>`?

Here's the example with the solution that I've found so far but am unhappy with. In order to create a `Stream<T>` from a `Stream<Collection<T>>`, I use `collect().stream()` with an intermediate `HashSet` (my `Collection` is a `Set`).

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.util.HashSet;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.security.Security.getProviders;
import static java.security.Provider.Service;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;

public class ListMessageDigests {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        stream(getProviders())
            .map(Provider::getServices)
            .collect(HashSet<Service>::new, HashSet::addAll, HashSet::addAll)
            .stream()
            .filter(service -> "MessageDigest".equals(service.getType()))
            .map(Service::getAlgorithm)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(out::println);
    }   
}
```

**Is there a more elegant way to convert a `Stream<Collection<T>>` to a `Stream<T>`?** Like a `Stream<Set<Service>>` in this example into a `Stream<Service>`? I am not happy with using an intermediate `HashSet` and `.collect().stream()`, it feels to complicated to me.

P.S.:
I know that I could've simply done this:

```
import static java.security.Security.getAlgorithms;
public class ListMessageDigests {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        getAlgorithms("MessageDigest")
            .forEach(out::println);
    }
}
```

I was only using `getProviders()` and `getServices` to quickly construct a `Stream<Set<Service>>` to have a `Stream<Collection<T>>` to demonstrate the question.

Comment: Instead of `algorithm -> out.format("%s%n", algorithm)` you can write `out::println` which is shorter and faster.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, you're right. I've updated my question and the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) with `Collection#stream`

```
<T> Stream<T> flatten(Stream<? extends Collection<? extends T>> stream){
    return stream.flatMap(Collection::stream);
}
```

The final code would then look like this:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.security.Provider.Service;
import static java.security.Security.getProviders;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;

public class ListMessageDigests {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        stream(getProviders())
            .flatMap(p -> p.getServices().stream())
            .distinct()
            .filter(service -> "MessageDigest".equals(service.getType()))
            .map(Service::getAlgorithm)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(out::println);
    }
}
```

Note that without calling [`distinct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) this might not result in a stream with exactly the same elements as your example, since collecting into a set will remove duplicates if there are any.

Comment: you could replace `.map(Provider::getServices)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)` with `.flatMap(p -> p.getServices().stream())`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, you're right. I've updated my question and the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for pointing out `distinct`. I've updated the answer accordingly.